# golang time.Format() gives different results for the same unix timestamp

Tags: go, time

time.Time initialized with time.Unix() and time.Parse() with exactly the same unix timestamp gives different results being printed with time.Format("2006-01-02")

The problem is not reproducible in playground, but I get it if I compile it myself.

My default time zone is Los Angeles, probably in different timezone result would be different.

> go version
>   go version go1.12.1 darwin/amd64
>
> go build
>
> ./test

test.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    control1 := time.Unix(1546300800, 0)
    test, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2019-01-01")

    fmt.Println("control:", control1.Unix(), control1.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Println("test:", test.Unix(), test.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

> ./test
>   control: 1546300800 2018-12-31
>   test: 1546300800 2019-01-01

So unix ts is the same (1546300800), but dates are different. Why?

Answer (score 4):

The printed dates are different because they have different timezones.

[`time.Unix()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) returns the **local Time**, while [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse):

> Elements omitted from the value are assumed to be zero or, when zero is impossible, one, so parsing "3:04pm" returns the time corresponding to Jan 1, year 0, 15:04:00 **UTC** (note that because the year is 0, this time is before the zero Time).

`time.Parse()` returns a `time.Time` having `UTC` zone by default (if zone info is not part of the input and layout).

This also explains why you can't see it on the Go Playground: the local time there is UTC.

Printing the zone info in my local computer (CET timezone):

```
fmt.Println("control:", control1.Unix(), control1.Format("2006-01-02 -0700"))
fmt.Println("test   :", test.Unix(), test.Format("2006-01-02 -0700"))

fmt.Println(control1.Zone())
fmt.Println(test.Zone())
```

Outputs:

```
control: 1546300800 2019-01-01 +0100
test   : 1546300800 2019-01-01 +0000
CET 3600
UTC 0
```

If you switch both times to the same zone (e.g. `UTC` or local), the printed dates will be the same:

```
control1 = control1.UTC()
test = test.UTC()
```

After this, the output:

```
control: 1546300800 2019-01-01 +0000
test   : 1546300800 2019-01-01 +0000
UTC 0
UTC 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't expect two dates with the same underlying unix timestamp output different results.

Comment: @serggp those are not two dates, it's the same instant in time, which is then formatted differently. It's frequent when the same knowledge/data is represented differently: eg `two` (the number) can be represented as `2` (decimal), `10` (binary), `two` (English), etc. But even though the representation is different, it carries the same payload.